# issue with uploading image using ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

the ajax call for posting an image :

```
function FileUploadCheck() {
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('LogoImageUploader', jQuery('#LogoImageUploader')[0].files[0]);

  jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",       
          url: "FileUploadChecker.php",
          contentType: "multipart/form-data",         
          data: formData,
          processData: false, 
          contentType: false,
          success : function(result){
              alert(result);

          }
        });
}
```

i assume the image is getting posted successfully
[image: request payload for the post request]

at the php script end :

```
<?php

echo var_dump($_FILES); 

?>
```

All of the above code works fine for me when i make use of jquery 1.7.2 but I can not keep using the jquery as other JS libraries existent in application as incompatible with the jquery 1.7.2 . I need to know if i could only import any standalone JS (maybe which provides ajax functionality) to make this work similar to jquery 1.7.2.

Comment: You should try this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18324384/4514250

Comment: Check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: If i am right you are missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form...

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this :

```
function FileUploadCheck() {
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('LogoImageUploader', jQuery('#LogoImageUploader')[0].files[0]);

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "FileUploadChecker.php";

    http.open("POST", url, true);

    //when i uncommentated this line, the upload failed, as i tried to manually set the header to the post, but i let XHR to set the header automatically this works.   
    //http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");



    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(formData);
}
```